# Exception to 'rescue_from Exception' for CanCan::AccessDenied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, custom-error-handling

I have implemented custom error handling, and used this line to rescue from errors:

```
rescue_from Exception,
  :with => :render_error
```

However, this is also rescuing from CanCan::AccessDenied, how can I make an exception to this rule to rescue 'CanCan::AccessDenied' and send to root path and rescue everything with the custom method ':render error'?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting directly from [the source](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html),

> Handlers are inherited. They are searched from right to left, from
>   bottom to top, and up the hierarchy. The handler of the first class
>   for which exception.is_a?(klass) holds true is the one invoked, if
>   any.

So, you can simply do this:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied, :with => :your_custom_handler
rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_error
```

Remember that the order of the rescue_from invocations is important.

Comment: The Order unfortunately made no difference

Comment: Please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094078/custom-error-handling-and-cancan